# SDXC-карта. Диск защищён от записи

Tags: память, sd

никакие файлы не грузятся в него.
Пытался сделать форматирование не получилось, даже лез в командную строку две команды пробовал для форматирования - ни черта.
карта памяти SmartBuy microSDXC 64gb

Comment: Там на карте есть физический переключатель защиты от записи

Comment: физических переключателей нету

Comment: я как понял, вы подумали не о microSD, если так, то извиняюсь, забываю о существовании их братьев.

Comment: Ну на переходнике переключатель тогда? Или вы напрямую без переходника куда-то воткнули?

Comment: карта памяти была без переходника. В моём ноутбуке есть гнездо для микроСД и я вставляю туда

Comment: Тогда наверное можно предположить, что карта умерла

Comment: боюсь у меня для вас дурные вести... последний раз когда я покупал что то от этой фирмы, это были 2 или 3 патрона для обычных лампочек и вот ведь не задача, стандартная лампочка не влезла ни в один из них. чтоб вы понимали, в попытках "вкрутить невкручиваемое" и цоколь лампочки поцарапал и потом колбу из него вырвал... и да, лампочка была выкручена из другого такого же патрона но старого и не этой фирмы(во влажном месте, контакты заржавели). в принципе и до этой покупки были неслабые подозрения, просто наклейку не заметил... надеюсь намёк ясен :3

Comment: Попробуйте снять защиту командой diskpart

Answer (score 0):

Если на пальцах, то табличка совместимости SD карточек и девайсов примерно вот такая:

[image: https://www.delkin.com/products/secure-digital/]

Т.е. если у вас девайс не SDXC, то и карточку SDXC он нормально не будет поддерживать.

Comment: В 2023 году вообще реально найти устройство, не умеющее SDXC?

Comment: @andreymal это уже ТС надо спрашивать, на чем он карточку открывает )

Comment: `это уже ТС надо спрашивать, на чем он карточку открывает` дык выше ж он писал `В моём` **`ноутбуке есть гнездо для микроСД`** `и я вставляю туда` начиная с SDHC между этими стандартами наиболее значимая разница лишь в используемой ФС, за её поддержку отвечает не сам слот с контроллером, а ОС и установленные в ней драйвера. если верить вики для SDXC нужен exFAT, а на винде он из коробки есть аж с висты(с обновлениями есть и в XP sp2+). валяется у меня где то нетбук времен XP, там вообще полноразмерный SD слот а не микро. так что... врятли дело может быть хоть в чем то кроме самой карты.

Comment: @puffleeck гадаете на гуще. Впрочем если оформите это как ответ, мб плюсик и будет )

Comment: @Kromster, найдется сильно согласный - плюсанет и камент, ответом это в любом случае не является, скорей дополнение к имеющемуся) `гадаете на гуще` о да, это я умею =) *а тем временем, гущи на дне банки осталось... эх...*